# Google App Engine having issues with __autoload

Tags: php, google-app-engine, autoload

Yesterday I started developing on the Google App Engine platform for the first time. After running into some minor newbie issues which I could easily resolve using the documentation, I now seem to have run into a trickier one. For some reason the following __autoload function doesn't work when I run it in a GAE sandbox.

```
function __autoload($classname)
{
    if(file_exists('system/core/'.$classname.'.php'))
    {
        include('system/core/'.$classname.'.php');
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'The class "'.$classname.'" could not be found!';
    }
}
```

The file does exist and when I use my normal LAMP stack it has no issues. Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: try to log the current working directory with `cwd` and check if the relative path is proper.

Comment: @AxelAmthor the current working directory is alright. I tried printing "test" at the beginning of the __autoload function, but it doesn't appear. Seems to me the __autoload function for some reason doesn't get called at all.

Comment: ok, that points in another direction: is there an autoloader already registered by the GAE environment? i.e. http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: Axel is correct. GAE has an autoloader registered already: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Automatic_class_loading